# Error shows after i tried to run my code, i cant find out whats the cause of the error

Tags: next.js

[its been 4 days straight just to find this error, but i still cant found out what's the cause of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCL2Q.png)

I've tried npm install and reinstalling everything but some how it still show's the same kind of error, i dont know whats the cause is

Comment: it does works but now it shows 404 on the page

Comment: Check that the URL is `http://localhost:3000` and nothing else. I mean you are on the root of the URL.

Comment: try to stop the server an delete the .next folder and then type npm run build to rebuild it